# How to tell when a user is logged in with Yii, in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, yii

The site I'm working on has a Yii section and a Wordpress section. I am currently unsure how to check if a user is logged in with the Yii site while in the Wordpress section, or if it is even possible to do so.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is include the `wp-load.php` file in the `index.php` of Yii and after that, you will be able to use all the wordpress functions, including `is_user_logged_in()`.

and also check this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/

hope it will help you.Thank you.

Comment: could you tell me how to do that exactly? I'm having a little trouble figuring it out.

Comment: It seems like he was asking how to check if a user was logged in to the yii side while on the WordPress side, your answer would be the other way around.